# ¿Como evitar me cree componentes de todos al hacer un ngFor en Angular?

Tags: angular, herencia, component, ngfor

La verdad es que estoy usando accordion(ui semantic) para mostrar y desplegar preguntas y respuestas.
 Imagina que quieres hacer una vista que muestre diferentes temáticas. Es decir un ngfor para diferentes enfermedades.
 - primer ngfor enseña las enfermedades.

al pulsar en uno de ellos te sale y despliega gracias a accordion y ngfor todos las preguntas que se han hecho por los usuarios de esa enfermedad (uno puede ser 10 y otro 200 preguntas).
[image: Desplegable con accordion y ngfor en angular]

en pregunta he insertado un boton que si lo pulso ne hace y muestra un desplegable o formulario pequeño de esa enfermedad para realizar una pregunta. Ese formulario esta en un componente hijo que se muestra.

Mi problema es que he usado propiedades de html y div para esconderlo, pero solo lo esconde, no evito que lo realice en todos los ngfor.

```
<div  id="nuevaPregunta{{Enfermedad.id}}" hidden>

    <app-form-pregunta  [AuxEnfermedad]="Enfermedad"  ></app-form-pregunta>
  </div>                             
</div>
```

Se ve que con eso solo hago NO lo muestre, no que no lo cree. Yo quisiera que el app-form-pregunta NO fuese creado más que en UNA de las enfermedades donde deseo hacer la pregunta. ¿Como lo hago?

Gracias.

NOTA: Un compañero me aconseja usar ngif (Gracias mil) , pero no lo consigo. Pongo en mi método em .ts

```
mostrarFormPregunta(idEn:string){

  this.entroFormPregunta= true

  if (document.getElementById(idEn).hidden == true) {
     document.getElementById(idEn).hidden=false;
  } else {
     document.getElementById(idEn).hidden=true;
  }


}
```

y en mi html uso....

```
<!--1 Hacer boton para realizar pregunta de enfermedad-->
<div *ngIf ="autenticado">                  
  <button (click)="mostrarFormPregunta('nuevaPregunta' + Enfermedad.id)" name="boton_Hacer_Pregunta" >
  Perguntar ahora {{Enfermedad.id}}</button>

  <div  id="nuevaPregunta{{Enfermedad.id}}"  hidden>
    <div *ngIf ="entroFormPregunta" >
    <app-form-pregunta  [AuxEnfermedad]="Enfermedad"  ></app-form-pregunta>
    </div>
  </div>                             
</div>
<!--1 Hacer boton para realizar pregunta de enfermedad-->
```

Tampoco si en vez de lo de arriba hago:

```
<!--1 Hacer boton para realizar pregunta de enfermedad-->
<div *ngIf ="autenticado">                  
  <button (click)="mostrarFormPregunta('nuevaPregunta' + Enfermedad.id)" name="boton_Hacer_Pregunta" >
  Preguntar ahora {{Enfermedad.id}}</button>

  <div  id="nuevaPregunta{{Enfermedad.id}}"  hidden>

    <div *ngIf ='Enfermedad.id===entroFormPregunta' >

    <app-form-pregunta  [AuxEnfermedad]="Enfermedad"  ></app-form-pregunta>
    </div>
  </div>                             
</div>
<!--1 Hacer boton para realizar pregunta de enfermedad-->
```

y en componente:

```
mostrarFormPregunta(idEn:string){

   this.entroFormPregunta=idEn;

  if (document.getElementById(idEn).hidden == true) {
     document.getElementById(idEn).hidden=false;
  } else {
     document.getElementById(idEn).hidden=true;
  }


}
```

y tampoco.  ¿Qué hago mal?  Gracias

Comment: `ngIf` es lo que buscas. Puedes poner un ejemplo mínimo que replique el problema?Te recomiendo usar [stackblitz](http://stackblitz.com/) para ello. Y editar tu pregunta con el código que denota el problema. (No tiene que ser todo)

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar una aproximación como esta:

```
<div  id="nuevaPregunta{{Enfermedad.id}}" hidden>

    <app-form-pregunta  
     *ngIf='idPreguntaSeleccionada === Enfermedad.id'
     [AuxEnfermedad]="Enfermedad"  ></app-form-pregunta>
  </div>                             
</div>
```

En tu `component.ts` crear la variable `idPreguntaSeleccionada` y solo la asignas al dar click en tu `component.html` con algo así:

```html
<a href='javascript:void(0) 
   (click)='idPreguntaSeleccionada = Enfermedad.id' 
>Seleccionar</a>
```

> Te dejo un [ejemplo funcional](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zqghzm)
>   tratando de replicar el problema y la solución para entendernos un poco
>   mejor.

Comment: Gracias. Veo por donde vas. Es obvio (ahora que me lo has dicho, claro) intentar con ng if. Pero no va. En mi componente .ts pongo....

Comment: ````<div  id="nuevaPregunta{{Enfermedad.id}}"  hidden>
    {{entroFormPregunta}}----{{Enfermedad.id}}
    <div *ngIf ='Enfermedad.id==entroFormPregunta' >   ```` no me funciona, uno y otro son iguales 1---1 y no abre  formulario.

Comment: el ejemplo funcional solo abre una pantalla con mensaje de HOLA.

Comment: Sorry, no guarde los cambios, deja lo vuelvo hacer y actualizo.

Comment: @DANIEL Ya quedo.

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS. lo tengo funcionando. Me continua dando un error de controlAbstract . Pero es UNO, no todo el FOR. Gracias